# iPad app - custom top bar

Tags: ipad, toolbar

I am trying to develop an iPad app in which I need to have a custom top-bar. It will have a logo image at its left, a title and a segmented control buttons. I am trying to do it programmatically. I was not sure how I should put the image and segmented control buttons.

Any suggestions/directions are appreciated.

(I'm fairly new to the Cocoa-touch development environment.)

Comment: I suggest that you use interface builder.

Comment: Thanks grc. I tried to use IB. But, there is a navigation bar and not a plain toolbar. I understand that navigation bar will show the back button when the screen changes which is not needed for me. Correct me if I am wrong here. I also tried to add imageView onto the navigation bar. But it did not allow me to do it. So I thought I will have to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IB but don't try to use an Apple navigation bar.  Just use blank view and set the color you want or add a UIImageView for the background.  Add your logo image and segmented control to the same view.  Then set it up as an IBOutlet and you can toggle the whole thing on and off as needed and setup buttons for navigation if needed.